# Finding eigenpairs of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do you find the eigenpairs of this?

> Given two matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix} a& b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} a& -b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ where $b \neq 0$, find all eigenpairs of $A$ and $B$, and comment if the matrices are diagonalizable or not.

I plugged in the characteristic equation $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ and is unable to solve for $\lambda $. I got $\lambda ^2-a^2-b^2=0$ and it won't let me factorize. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{bmatrix}
is indeed $\lambda^2-a^2-b^2$. The eigenvalues are $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Since
$$A-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\,I=
\begin{bmatrix}
a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2} & b \\
b & -a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank one, an eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2} & b \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$
so we can take
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} b \\ \sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a\end{bmatrix}
$$
and this is nonzero, so it is a basis for the eigenspace. The other eigenvectors are the non zero scalar multiples of this one.

Similarly for the other eigenvalue.

For the matrix
\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}
the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-2a\lambda+(a^2+b^2)$, whose roots are
$a+ib$ and $a-ib$.

Assuming $a$ and $b$ real, the first matrix is diagonalizable, because it has distinct real eigenvalues. The second matrix is diagonalizable over the complex numbers, but not over the reals.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $\lambda^2 = a^2 + b^2$, then the eigenvalue is $$\lambda = \pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

From there you can find the eigenvectors.

Edit:

If we want to find a particular $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} z_1 & z_2 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}=0$, we can just pick $x_1=-z_2, x_2=z_1.$

Comment: Now I have \begin{pmatrix}b&-a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} and I don't know how to proceed further. As long as x1 and x2 satisfy the equation, it's okay. So do I just say there are infinite number of eigenvectors?

Comment: See the edit. We usually just care about linearly independent set of eigenvectors.

Comment: I don't understand, x1 and x2 can be anything.

Comment: hmm... $x_1$ and $x_2$ must satisfies $z_1x_1+z_2x_2=0$ right? they can't just be anything. perhaps rather than $x_1$ and $x_2$, you might like to view it as $x$ and $y$ and view $z_1 x + z_2 y = 0$ is a straight line that passes through the origin right.

Comment: So do we just say the eigenvectors are x1=−z2, x2=z1?

Comment: An eigenvector that corresponds to $\lambda_1$ is $v_1$. Eigenvectors are not unique.

Comment: But I don't know how to answer the question. The question asks me to find ALL eigenvectors, which is impossible. Cuz there are too many.

Comment: they are multiple of each other, for this particular example, you might want to find a non-zero eigenvecotr, call it $v_1$, then the set of eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue is ${kv_1|k \in \mathbb{R}\}$. btw, you might want to start with numerical examples rather than an abstract exercise first.

Comment: I found v1 = (-(-a + sqrt(a^2 + b^2))/b, 1) and v2 = (-(-a - sqrt(a^2 + b^2))/b, 1). What does your code mean?

Comment: oh dear, I was too sleepy and the code didn't work out. I was trying to describe the whole set of eigenvectors. Your $v_1$ corresponds to eigenvalue $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ right?

Comment: Yes, and v2 corresponds to the other eigenvalue.